# How to Select and upload the file to katalon extension

Tags: katalon-studio

We select the upload file for automation script. it's showing the fake path like this. (C:\fakepath\Clients.pdf) but I run the script again it's not working.

```
    open    https://testeastaccount.pascalapp.com/app/dashboard 
click   //li[@id='Documents']/a/div/i   
click   xpath=(//button[@type='button'])[3] 
click   link=Add Document   
click   name=contact_rec    
type    name=contact_rec    c
click   //div[@id='Upload-document']/form/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li[10]/a    
click   link=Grant Linked Accounts Access   
click   link=Grant Linked Accounts Access   
click   //div[@id='Upload-document']/form/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/button  
selectFrame index=11    
click   //html[@id='ng-app']/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/section/div/div/button  
type    //input[@type='file']   C:\personal\Clients.pdf
click   //html[@id='ng-app']/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/section[2]/div[2]/button[2] 
selectFrame relative=parent 
click   name=yeartags   
select  name=yeartags   label=Tax Year 2015
click   xpath=(//option[@value='2015'])[2]  
click   xpath=(//textarea[@name='description'])[4]  
type    xpath=(//textarea[@name='description'])[4]  dfd
click   //textarea[@name='contact'] 
type    //textarea[@name='contact'] ffdfdffd
click   //div[@id='Upload-document']/form/div[3]/button[2]  
click   link=exact:Document Firm Tags * 
click   //div[@id='tagsdiv']/ul/li[2]/div/label/span    
click   //div[@id='tagsdiv']/ul/li[3]/div/label/span    
click   link=exact:Document Firm Tags * 
click   //div[@id='Upload-document']/form/div[3]/button[2]  
click   //div[@id='Upload-document']/form/div[3]/button
```

Comment: What do you mean "run the script again"? Could you show your script please?

Comment: Could you please update your question with code snippet in human-readable format?

Comment: yes, sir, I update my question with code.

Comment: Thanks! So is it working in the first execution and fails in the second? Or just recorded it?

Comment: only just recorded.

Comment: You should try to record `//input[@type='file']` element again with Object Spy. Maybe you recorded not the right xpath.

Comment: Have you fixed it successfully?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Object spy` to record element again. Most of the time, reason of these errors is, that wrong web element is recorded. You can try to use another identifier(s) of the same element.

Comment: @RenuThakur : Field/element has to be `input` type. Is it?

Comment: No, Sir its select file button. ANd  i used the katalon extension

Comment: I see know, but you used tag katalon-studio. I think Katalon Studio would be better for this purpose, I am not sure, that browser extension can handle file upload properly.

Comment: Ok sir, But what can i do now?

Comment: @RenuThakur : Try to use Katalon Studio for this purpose: https://www.katalon.com/ You can also record scripts with this tool.